# How to make every new process created to run on a separate terminals?

Tags: 18.04

We were asked to create a process S which receives inputs from a process P1 connected by a pipe,a process P2 connected by using command popen and another process P3 connected by fifo.There is no problem in making the connections.The problem is the processes S,P1 and P2 are running in the same terminal.So if we type something,we dont know as to where the input goes to .It can input to S,P1 or P2.
So I would like to know if there is any way as to create a new terminal whenever a process is created.

Comment: Hint: named pipes is what you want, aka named fifo. As for separate terminals, there is no need

Comment: `We were asked to create ..` is this school-work or a paid job you are doing ? AU don't do your homework.

Comment: It is college assignment

Comment: I know the problem would be solved with named pipes.I would like to know if there is any way to start a new terminal for every user defined process created.